# Applying PCA gives nan values in reduced matrix; how to apply successful dimensionality reduction

Tags: python, pca

I am using Python. I apply kernel PCA with 'rbf' kernels (I tried the other options as well) using Python's KernelPCA package from sklearn.

When doing so, I get the warning

```
"RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
return np.dot(K, self.alphas_ / np.sqrt(self.lambdas_))"
```

the lambdas are the eigenvalues of the matrix. I believe the error is that the eigenvalues are NaN.

The PCA is still performed (the above is "just" a warning), but the resultant reduced matrix has NaN values in certain columns which seems to indicate something is wrong (not just a warning, but actually wrong).

Basically, how do I proceed/interpret this result?

Does it make sense to simply ignore those NaN columns and use the reduced matrix? The reason why I think not is because what then happens to the inverse map (going from the reduced to the full matrix)? But then again, sklearn didn't give an error *per se*, so maybe there is hope?

I am not an expert on PCA. The original/full matrix has ~350 columns and 200 rows. Standardizing the matrix before PCA (mean zero and unit variance) does not help. Does anybody know what is going on/how to analyze what is wrong?

I am open to other dimensionality reduction techniques if possible.

My idea now is to reduce the matrix until it behaves well and sort of iteratively build it to the point of breaking. But, in the end, I would prefer using the entire matrix as is (or at least be able to say that the matrix is so bad that I will never be able to do PCA, or something).

Comment: `np.sqrt` returns `nan` when the argument is negative. So you might get negative eigenvalues. According to an answer here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/317549, "Negative eigenvalues with a significant magnitude indicate a serious model misspecification." I don't know what that means more specifically though.

Comment: Update: I found that the problem was with the matrix. I had many columns of the same value and ended up removing duplicate columns which stabilized the whole thing.